# Automatic Sizing of an imported EMF image file

Tags: images, microsoft-word-2010

I create full page, landscape images in PPT/PPTX, then create an EMF file of each.  I have a script that automatically imports the EMF files at the proper location, but then they have to be manually resized.  With over 400 images, this is labor intensive.  All the EMF File images need to be the same dimensions in the WORD document, before it is converted to PDF.  How can ensure the images are properly dimensioned and centered within the margins during the automated import?

Answer (score 0):

1. Start recording a macro.
2. Do what you do to manually resize an image.
3. Stop recording the macro.
4. See if you can use that macro to resize other images. 
   You may need to tweak it.